# Encountering issue regarding the installatiion of byte track on my pycharm project

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, computer-vision, issue-tracking

(venv) PS C:\Users\PycharmProjects\python-1> pip install bytetrack
Collecting bytetrack
Using cached bytetrack-0.0.1.tar.gz (100 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: bytetrack
Building wheel for bytetrack (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [130 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
C:\Users\najma.hanif\PycharmProjects\python-1\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py:500: UserWarning: Attempted to use ninja as the BuildExtension backend but we could not find ninja.. Falling back to using t
he slow distutils backend.
warnings.warn(msg.format('we could not find ninja.'))
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack
copying bytetrack_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\core
copying bytetrack\core\launch.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\core
copying bytetrack\core\trainer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\core
copying bytetrack\core_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\core
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\data
copying bytetrack\data\dataloading.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\data
copying bytetrack\data\data_augment.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\data
copying bytetrack\data\data_prefetcher.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\data
copying bytetrack\data\samplers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\data
copying bytetrack\data_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\data
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\deepsort_tracker
copying bytetrack\deepsort_tracker\deepsort.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\deepsort_tracker
copying bytetrack\deepsort_tracker\detection.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\deepsort_tracker
copying bytetrack\deepsort_tracker\iou_matching.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\deepsort_tracker
copying bytetrack\deepsort_tracker\kalman_filter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\deepsort_tracker
copying bytetrack\deepsort_tracker\linear_assignment.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\deepsort_tracker
copying bytetrack\deepsort_tracker\reid_model.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\deepsort_tracker
copying bytetrack\deepsort_tracker\track.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\deepsort_tracker
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\evaluators
copying bytetrack\evaluators\coco_evaluator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\evaluators
copying bytetrack\evaluators\evaluation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\evaluators
copying bytetrack\evaluators\mot_evaluator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\evaluators
copying bytetrack\evaluators_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\evaluators
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\exp
copying bytetrack\exp\base_exp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\exp
copying bytetrack\exp\build.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\exp
copying bytetrack\exp\yolox_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\exp
copying bytetrack\exp_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\exp
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\layers
copying bytetrack\layers\fast_coco_eval_api.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\layers
copying bytetrack\layers_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\layers
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\models
copying bytetrack\models\darknet.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\models
copying bytetrack\models\losses.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\models
copying bytetrack\models\network_blocks.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\models
copying bytetrack\models\yolox.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\models
copying bytetrack\models\yolo_fpn.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\models
copying bytetrack\models\yolo_head.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\models
copying bytetrack\models\yolo_pafpn.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\models
copying bytetrack\models_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\models
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\motdt_tracker
copying bytetrack\motdt_tracker\basetrack.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\motdt_tracker
copying bytetrack\motdt_tracker\kalman_filter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\motdt_tracker
copying bytetrack\motdt_tracker\matching.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\motdt_tracker
copying bytetrack\motdt_tracker\motdt_tracker.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\motdt_tracker
copying bytetrack\motdt_tracker\reid_model.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\motdt_tracker
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\sort_tracker
copying bytetrack\sort_tracker\sort.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\sort_tracker
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tools
copying bytetrack\tools\convert_cityperson_to_coco.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tools
copying bytetrack\tools\convert_crowdhuman_to_coco.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tools
copying bytetrack\tools\convert_ethz_to_coco.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tools
copying bytetrack\tools\convert_mot17_to_coco.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tools
copying bytetrack\tools\convert_mot20_to_coco.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tools
copying bytetrack\tools\convert_video.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tools
copying bytetrack\tools\demo_track.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tools
copying bytetrack\tools\export_onnx.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tools
copying bytetrack\tools\interpolation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tools
copying bytetrack\tools\mix_data_ablation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tools
copying bytetrack\tools\mix_data_test_mot17.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tools
copying bytetrack\tools\mix_data_test_mot20.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tools
copying bytetrack\tools\mota.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tools
copying bytetrack\tools\track.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tools
copying bytetrack\tools\track_deepsort.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tools
copying bytetrack\tools\track_motdt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tools
copying bytetrack\tools\track_sort.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tools
copying bytetrack\tools\train.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tools
copying bytetrack\tools\trt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tools
copying bytetrack\tools\txt2video.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tools
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tracker
copying bytetrack\tracker\basetrack.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tracker
copying bytetrack\tracker\byte_tracker.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tracker
copying bytetrack\tracker\kalman_filter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tracker
copying bytetrack\tracker\matching.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tracker
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tracking_utils
copying bytetrack\tracking_utils\evaluation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tracking_utils
copying bytetrack\tracking_utils\io.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tracking_utils
copying bytetrack\tracking_utils\timer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\tracking_utils
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\utils
copying bytetrack\utils\allreduce_norm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\utils
copying bytetrack\utils\boxes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\utils
copying bytetrack\utils\checkpoint.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\utils
copying bytetrack\utils\demo_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\utils
copying bytetrack\utils\dist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\utils
copying bytetrack\utils\ema.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\utils
copying bytetrack\utils\logger.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\utils
copying bytetrack\utils\lr_scheduler.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\utils
copying bytetrack\utils\metric.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\utils
copying bytetrack\utils\model_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\utils
copying bytetrack\utils\setup_env.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\utils
copying bytetrack\utils\visualize.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\utils
copying bytetrack\utils_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\utils
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\data\datasets
copying bytetrack\data\datasets\datasets_wrapper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\data\datasets
copying bytetrack\data\datasets\mosaicdetection.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\data\datasets
copying bytetrack\data\datasets\mot.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\data\datasets
copying bytetrack\data\datasets_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\data\datasets
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\deploy
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\deploy\ONNXRuntime
copying bytetrack\deploy\ONNXRuntime\onnx_inference.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\bytetrack\deploy\ONNXRuntime
running build_ext
C:\Users\najma.hanif\PycharmProjects\python-1\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py:381: UserWarning: Error checking compiler version for cl: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
warnings.warn(f'Error checking compiler version for {compiler}: {error}')
building 'bytetrack._C' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\Users
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\Users\najma.hanif
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\Users\najma.hanif\AppData
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\Users\najma.hanif\AppData\Local
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\Users\najma.hanif\AppData\Local\Temp
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\Users\najma.hanif\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ilqdme43
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\Users\najma.hanif\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ilqdme43\bytetrack_532cc909e0444f94b236ac0a8f610b30
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\Users\najma.hanif\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ilqdme43\bytetrack_532cc909e0444f94b236ac0a8f610b30\bytetrack
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\Users\najma.hanif\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ilqdme43\bytetrack_532cc909e0444f94b236ac0a8f610b30\bytetrack\layers
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\Users\najma.hanif\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ilqdme43\bytetrack_532cc909e0444f94b236ac0a8f610b30\bytetrack\layers\csrc
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\najma.hanif\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ilqdme43\bytetrack
_532cc909e0444f94b236ac0a8f610b30\bytetrack\layers\csrc -IC:\Users\najma.hanif\PycharmProjects\python-1\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\include -IC:\Users\najma.hanif\PycharmProjects\python-1\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\include\to
rch\csrc\api\include -IC:\Users\najma.hanif\PycharmProjects\python-1\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\include\TH -IC:\Users\najma.hanif\PycharmProjects\python-1\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\include\THC -IC:\Users\najma.hanif\Pycharm
Projects\python-1\venv\include "-IC:\Program Files\Python312\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python312\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program File
s (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\um" "-IC:\Program Fil
es (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)
\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /TpC:\Users\najma.hanif\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ilqdme43\bytetrack_532cc909e0444f94b236ac0a8f610b30\bytetrack\layers\csrc\vision.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release
\Users\najma.hanif\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ilqdme43\bytetrack_532cc909e0444f94b236ac0a8f610b30\bytetrack\layers\csrc\vision.obj /MD /wd4819 /wd4251 /wd4244 /wd4267 /wd4275 /wd4018 /wd4190 /wd4624 /wd4067 /wd4068 /EHsc -O3
-DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_C -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 /std:c++17
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-O3'
vision.cpp
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'C:\Users\najma.hanif\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ilqdme43\bytetrack_532cc909e0444f94b236ac0a8f610b30\bytetrack\layers\csrc\vision.cpp': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for bytetrack
Running setup.py clean for bytetrack
Failed to build bytetrack
ERROR: Could not build wheels for bytetrack, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
(venv) PS C:\Users\najma.hanif\PycharmProjects\python-1>

I tried to download directly from thegithub and placed the library inside my python project , after that it showed the lap import error and then again it encounters the same sub-process exist error.
Please help i ve tough deadlines.